# Single Page Website - is this a good way?

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I have a website and i want to simulate a Single Page Application on my static website. He has just 5 pages without back end calls.

Here is a way that i saw on Google:

**index.html**

```
<body>
<a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Go to Home</a>
<div id="content">
    <h1>I will be substitute to the homepage</h1>
</div>
<script>
    function load_home(){
      fetch('home.html')
        .then(function(response) {
            // output response.text(): <h1>home</h1>
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.text() 
        })
    }
</script>
</body>
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

The button `Go to Home` load the home.html by a `fetch`, the page will not reload and it will simulate a SPA experience.
Is there another way to do that with **Javascript**?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes; there are many ways to build SPAs.  You should use a framework like React.  What don't you understand?

Comment: It is a way to build a SPA without any framework. But i dont know if this is a good way. Is it?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Use https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks or a similar library instead. Your suggestion seems half-baked and has many disadvantages.

Comment: @SLaks i'm not intending do that, i just want to know if this is a good way. because i saw simulates like web pages been controlled by CSS using `display: none`... i think that this is a very bad way.

Comment: @str can you explain to me these disadvantages? I'm very curious to know. =)

Comment: It does not work without JavaScript, search engines might no be able to crawl it, there are no deeplinks (i.e. no bookmarking, no sharing, you cannot open pages in a new tab), browser history does not work, ...

Comment: Yes, you can make a very simple SPA with just AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers guys. I will take a look on this *turbilinks* , it seems good :) !!

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide is just an alphabet of the whole concept. It's good but it will not be enough for *Single Page Web Application (SPWA)* when you will start to add functionality to the web app.

*Single Page Web Application (SPWA)* **can be achieved by vanilla HTML5, CSS3 JavaScript and a server-side language like PHP, Python etc.** You should try to make one or two project using only HTML5,CSS3,JavaScript and your server-side language of love(PHP is be easier for most beginner). Then you should learn framework for rapid prototyping and development. You can learn AngularJs, ReactJs ,Bootstrap, Materialize CSS, Laravel etc. and deep dive to the world of web development. There is always more then one way but go which you love.

Comment: As i said, it is a static website, it will never be a webapp. but thanks for answer! :)